# How to download msdn library for C++

Tags: c, visual-c++, documentation, msdn

I want to download all the library documentation about ,msvc++ from MSDN. I don't have access to internet for more than 12 hours in a day . It's creating a lot of problem for me. Can anybody give me idea to locally store entire documentation. Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I got it for visual studio 2008. If anybody gets for 2010, kindly provide me a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem ? download MSDN using download manager (it can stop the download and resume it later. and set the help to go for local copy of the documentation.

it works.

what visual studio do you use ?
[MSDN 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373&DisplayLang=en)

For 2010 it looks like they did not published an iso download but I've found this post:
[Downloading MSDN 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/devdocs/thread/73123770-b8d9-425f-96b1-90c1983bf133) :

While no downloadable ISO is available, you can use the Help Manager in VS 2010 to download Help onto your local machine.

To get this, click Manage Help Settings on the Help menu.

If you click Install content from disk, a local version of MSDN library is downloaded onto your machine. Click Choose online or local help and then I want to use local help if you want to use the downloaded content versus online Help content. Of course, the Help downloaded from the disk is only a snapshot taken at RTM, so it lacks topic updates.  To get updates (if they're available), click Check for updates online.

HTH,
- Kemp Brown [MSFT]

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010. Is there any download link available to directrly download MSDN? Let me search.

Comment: if you have msdn subscription - it is in the subscriber's download section, I'll add a link to the public download to the answer